# Translating htaccess file to web_config / IIS

Tags: .htaccess, iis, plesk

I have been driven around the bend trying to figure this out and I'm at the point I don't know what I am doing wrong and also what I am actually doing.

I have just moved from a Linux shared host running Plesk to a Dedi Windows server with Plesk installed on it. I have moved everything across files wise, DNS etc.

However, when I visited the sites I realised that when I navigated to a page which isn't the index it will give me a 404 error page. After some investigating, I realised that Plesk Linux uses Apache a.k.a .htaccess files compared to Windows Plesk using IIS a.k.a web_config file. I know my issue is that my new server isn't handling the exclusion of file extensions in the url. However, the issue I am having is I tried converting my below .htaccess files using [this online converter](https://cbsa.com.br/tools/online-convert-htaccess-to-web-config.aspx) into a web_config file however I keep getting internal server errors. I then read [this solution](https://www.saotn.org/convert-htaccess-web-config/) which says you can import .htaccess code to use in the IIS manager however the IIS manager keeps giving errors or when it says everything is okay my websites still give the 404 error message.

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be super helpful!

The two .htaccess files I use and trying to convert are as follows, also if they are messy blame my friend as he made them for me. One which denies looking at the directories, removing html, php file extensions and cache which can be seen below and the second is just a simple deny from all that I put into the directory where I am storing database connection details etc.

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

# Remove www from any URLs that have them:
RewriteEngine on



# Three days for most static assets
<filesMatch ".(htaccess|css|jpg|jpeg|png|js|php|html)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public, must-revalidate"
    </IfModule>
</filesMatch>
Options All -Indexes

# deny access to evil robots site rippers offline browsers and other nasty scum
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Anarchie [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ASPSeek [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^attach [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^autoemailspider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xenu [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus.*Webster [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

```html
Deny From All
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below web.config code with your iis site:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
               <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="craftbot|download|extract|stripper|sucker|ninja|clshttp|webspider|leacher|collector|grabber|webpictures" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403"
               statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied."
               statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this page." />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)/index\.php$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}/"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)/index\.html$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}/"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="!.*\.html$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html"  appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 6q" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="!.*\.php$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php"  appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
 </rules>
        </rewrite>

 <staticContent>
     <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public"    cacheControlMode="UseExpires"
        httpExpires="Tue, 19 Jan 2012 03:14:07 GMT" />
  </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Update:

```
<rule name=”PHP Hiding”>

 <match url=”(.*)” />

     <conditions logicalGrouping=”MatchAll”>

         <add input=”{REQUEST_FILENAME}” matchType=”IsFile” negate=”true” />

         <add input=”{REQUEST_FILENAME}” matchType=”IsDirectory” negate=”true” />

     </conditions>

 <action type=”Rewrite” url=”{R:1}.php” />
```

Note: you can modify the values based on your requirement.

Comment: I just tried this code and in the IIS it shows the rules as well but nothing seems to have changed. Any page which isn't an index page gives a 404 error message.

This is the site which works fine: https://paradiseliferp.net
I applied the above but this page is still error 404: https://paradiseliferp.net/branding
However, you can see it's a valid page by adding the file extension https://paradiseliferp.net/branding.php

Comment: @SenkaWolf could you try the updated rule

Comment: I apologise for such a late response! I've just tried adding this to the web.config file but I got the Error: Configuration file is not well-formatted XML. I am assuming I am putting this into the file in the wrong place? Where should this code be put to be formatted correctly?